# How to declare a global variable

Tags: php, variables

I used to be able to do this but now it is not working. 
I am not sure if it the PHP version that has caused this change. 
I understand that `include` and `require` will be able to do this but it causes a lot of issues when I'm trying to use it. I would appreciate any input as PHP is not in my best understanding.

**file1.php**

```
 <?php
 include "functions.php"
  $db = new Functions();

 if ($db->isUserExisted($accountemail)) {
        // user is already existed - error response
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
        error_log(print_r($response,true));
        echo json_encode($response);
  echo "weblogin-after checking existed"."<br>";

       }
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
 class Functions {
require "./config.php";//connecting to database
 public function isUserExisted($email) {
 global $con;

   echo"checking email";
    $result = "SELECT * from db WHERE Account_email = :email";

    $stmt = $con->prepare($result);
   $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $row =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $no_of_rows =$stmt->rowCount();
   echo $no_of_rows;

    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        return true;
    } else {
    error_log(print_r('user not existed',true));
        // user not existed
        return false;
     }
  }
 }
```

Right now it doesn't move passed `$db = new Functions();`. 
There are no PHP errors

config.php

```
<?php
  /**
   * DB uration variables
   */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$DB_HOST= "localhost";
$DB_USER="user";
$DB_PASSWORD= "****";
$DB_DATABASE="db";


try {

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=".$DB_HOST.";dbname=".$DB_DATABASE.";", $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
   $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  error_log(print_r('config',true));

  echo "Connected successfully "; 
  return $con;
  error_log('connect',true);
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
  error_log(print_r( "Error!: " . $e->getMessage()."<br/>" ,true)) ;
   error_log(print_r('not connected',true));
  die();
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: *How* is it not working? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: `function.php` or `functions.php`?

Comment: _"There are no php error"_ - then go research how to properly configure PHP's error reporting please.

Comment: Global variables aren't the way to go anyway.  They lead to tightly coupled, hard to debug, hard to maintain code filled with magic values.  Use the argument list of a function.  *That's why it's there*

Comment: Error reporting is enabled but no error. It shows to go to function.php when $db = new Functions(); is called. Then it goes to config.php(connecting to db). After that it should  call isUserExisted($accountemail but it doesn't. @CBroe- i corrected the file name.thnx

Answer (score 0):

You could first try to enable your PHP error reporting.
You could do so by putting the following code in your `file1.php` right after `<?php`

`ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);`